# Add config file based on deploymentName

Tags: java, grails, jboss, jndi

I am trying to load a config file that is specific to a deployment on a JBoss server. The idea is that I can have multiple deployments of the same application (Example, training, testing, development) on the same server. And each deployment will have a different configuration.

Right now the direction I'm taking is to get the deployment name from jboss via the JNDI. Here is a part from my grails-app/conf/Config.groovy

```
appCtx = new InitialContext().lookup("java:app")
if(appCtx) {
  deploymentName = appCtx.lookup("AppName")
  grails.config.locations << "classpath:${deploymentName}-config.properties"
  grails.config.locations << "classpath:${deploymentName}-config.groovy"
}
```

Then if I name the war file `training.war`, stick it in the `deployments` folder, then it should pick up a config from

```
configurations/training-config.properties
```

The issue I'm having is I get an error while packaging...

```
Need to specify class name in environment or system property,
or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:
java.naming.factory.initial
```

Anyone have ideas on how to fix this? Or if there's an easier way?

I'm using JBoss 7.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... it's as simple as placing the code in a try/catch block...

```
import javax.naming.Context
import javax.naming.InitialContext
try {
  Context appCtx = (Context)(new InitialContext().lookup("java:app"))

  // JBoss's deployment name
  // you can see this at Profile >> Container >> Naming >> applications
  deploymentName = appCtx.lookup("AppName")

  grails.config.locations << "classpath:${deploymentName}-config.properties"
  grails.config.locations << "classpath:${deploymentName}-config.groovy"
  if(System.properties["${deploymentName}.config.location"]) {
    grails.config.locations << "file:" +
      System.properties["${deploymentName}.config.location"]
  } else if(System.getenv("${deploymentName}.config.location")) {
    grails.config.locations << "file:" + 
      System.getenv("${deploymentName}.config.location")
  }
}catch(Exception ex) {
  // Initial Context does not exist
  // aka, not deployed
}
```

The modified code also allows for a system property or environment variable that specifies the deployment name. This can be configured via JBoss 7.1.1. For a deployed `training.war` application...

Profile >> General Configuration >> System Properties >> Add

Enter the key like so...

```
training.config.location
```

And the value/path. If on windows, double escape the path

```
E:\\Servers\\jboss\\jboss7.1.1\\standalone\\configurations\\training-config.properties
```

Then deploy the war file to jboss.  Configuration should be picked up. :D

Props go to Mike over at [this blog](http://phatness.com/2010/03/how-to-externalize-your-grails-configuration/) for coming up with the System properties/env variable idea